# Creating new stack navigator on top of a stack navigator

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

In iOS terms, I want to present `UINavigationController B` on top of `UINavigationController A`, for instance

1. User click a button from **Home** which starts a flow by presenting `UINavigationController B` (a new stack)
2. Dismissing this `UINavigationController B` will remove the presented stack and brings the user back to **Home**

and the code looks something like this

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: destination)
source.present(navController, animated: animated, completion: completion)

source        -> UINavigationController A
navController -> UINavigationController B
```

How do I achieve this in **React Native** using React Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The away that this kind of navigation is usually done is creating a component that contains your `NavigationController B` as a Route on `NavigationController A`

Something like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';

import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';
import Invoices from '../pages/Invoices';
import Profile from '../pages/Profile';
import Contacts from '../pages/Contacts';

const App = createStackNavigator();

const User = createStackNavigator();

const UserRoutes: React.FC = () => (
  <User.Navigator>
    <User.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
    <User.Screen name="Contacts" component={Contacts} />
  </User.Navigator>
)

const AppRoutes: React.FC = () => (
  <App.Navigator>
    <App.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
    <App.Screen name="User" component={UserRoutes} />
  </App.Navigator>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

The example above is using React Navigation v5 and Typescript.

You can create any kind of navigation nesting then as Routes.

Comment: I created a new screen, with similar setting, but I still can't access the screen by "/newScreen" path, why?